# Wait until getting data from localStorage before setting the state in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, local-storage

just trying to figure out what I may be doing wrong here. For some reason, the app just keeps getting into a loop and crashing when I pass in the variables in the dependency array. These are state variables from the context provider.

I am trying to get this useEffect hook to run everytime the variables in the dependency array is ran:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Setting default values
    const minSqFt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('minSqFt'));
    const maxSqFt = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('maxSqFt'));
    toggleBySqft(minSqFt, 'min');
    toggleBySqft(maxSqFt, 'max');

    const minPrice = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('minPrice'));
    const maxPrice = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('maxPrice'));
    toggleByPrice(minPrice, 'min');
    toggleByPrice(maxPrice, 'max');
  }, [filterBySqFt, filterByPrice]);
```

However, with this, it causes an infinite loop which eventually leads to the applicaton crashing.

Is there any way to wait until getting the data from localStorage before running the functions inside the useEffect so I don't have to pass a dependency array?

The filterBySqFt and filterByPrice are state variables from the context provider. It is being pulled in from props.

Here are some functions that are related to the above code but shouldn't have to do with the app crashing.

```
  const handleSelectSqFt = (e, param) => {
    if (param === 'min') localStorage.setItem('minSqFt', e.value);
    if (param === 'max') localStorage.setItem('maxSqFt', e.value);
  }

  const handleSelectPrice = (e, param) => {
    if (param === 'min') localStorage.setItem('minPrice', e.value);
    if (param === 'max') localStorage.setItem('maxPrice', e.value);
  }
```

And here is where I am using the functions. toggleByPrice and toggleBySqFt are the actual functions from the app context provider that updates the state in app context file:

```
<div>
            <h3 className={cl("filters_title")}>Price</h3>
            <div className={cl(["field_price"])}>
              <div className={cl("field_label")}>Min Price</div>
              <Select
                options={price_min_options}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  toggleByPrice(e.value, "min");
                  handleSelectPrice(e, "min");
                }}
                classNamePrefix={"select_filter"}
                className={"select_filter"}
                placeholder={
                  filterByPrice.min !== -1 ? filterByPrice.min : "Any"
                }
                isSearchable={false}
              />
            </div>
            <div className={cl(["field_price"])}>
              <div className={cl("field_label")}>Max Price</div>
              <Select
                options={price_max_options}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  toggleByPrice(e.value, "max");
                  handleSelectPrice(e, "max")
                }}
                classNamePrefix={"select_filter"}
                className={"select_filter"}
                placeholder={
                  filterByPrice.max !== -1 ? filterByPrice.max : "Any"
                }
                isSearchable={false}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <h3 className={cl("filters_title")}>Square Footage</h3>
            <div className={cl(["field_price"])}>
              <div className={cl("field_label")}>Min sq. ft.</div>
              <Select
                options={sqft_min_options}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  toggleBySqft(e.value, "min");
                  handleSelectSqFt(e, 'min');
                }}
                classNamePrefix={"select_filter"}
                className={"select_filter"}
                placeholder={filterBySqft.min !== -1 ? filterBySqft.min : "Any"}
              />
            </div>
            <div className={cl(["field_price"])}>
              <div className={cl("field_label")}>Max sq. ft.</div>
              <Select
                options={sqft_max_options}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  toggleBySqft(e.value, "max");
                  handleSelectSqFt(e, 'max');
                }}
                classNamePrefix={"select_filter"}
                className={"select_filter"}
                placeholder={filterBySqft.max !== -1 ? filterBySqft.max : "Any"}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: What's with the dependencies for your `useEffect` (`filterBySqFt` and `filterByPrice`)? I don't see where they're being used, unless they are supposed to be `toggleBy...`. Also, if they are functions, reading [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) might help. Functions as dependencies have do be done very carefully, if they are done at all (see "last resort...useCallback" in that FAQ)

Answer (score 0):

The `localStorage.getItem` method is synchronous, so in your example the data will always be retrieved prior to `toggleBySqft` being called. Your code is looping for a different reason. This is most likely due to `toggleBySqft` changing the values of either `filterBySqFt` or `filterByPrice`, or another dependency somewhere else.

Keep in mind that your dependencies should be used in your effect, in your examples they are not.